# Visual Studio Code and Flask Jinja Templates

Tags: flask, jinja2, visual-studio-code

I have recently switched to Visual Studio Code (previously used PyCharm) and am now facing a formatting problem.

With the following example html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block body %} 
{{ super() }}
  <div>Something</div>
{% endblock%}
```

after saving (I have turned on formatOnSave) I get the following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}{% block body %}{{ super() }}
<div>Something</div>{% endblock%}
```

I am using the [editorconfig plugin](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode) and have stayed with the default user settings.

How can I configure VSC to not force Jinja blocks to be on a single line?

Comment: I posted a great working solution here: [Visual Studio Code and Jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761998/9152905)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [known issue](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode/issues/153) with trailing spaces.

You might try another extension dedicated to jinja: https://github.com/wholroyd/vscode-jinja

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary solution for that. 
Use [Better Jinja](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml) extension and add to jinja2 files .html.j2 extension.
You lose build-in HTML formatting but preserve jinja2 syntax :)

Comment: Better Jinja is great, and it keeps HTML highlighting.  But I lose features like autocomplete & auto-tag-closing.  Any way to re-enable those features?

Comment: instead of changing extensions you can add   `"files.associations": { "*.html": "jinja-html"}`  to settings.json

Comment: @bjg222 to keep html features and jinja snippets, I combine [flask-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cstrap.flask-snippets) with the html editor. When I open a html.j2 template, I can [change the language to HTML](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) to keep the features of html editor but with snippets for jinja like `fif` (`if`), `ffor` (`for`), etc. To keep syntax highlighting for jinja instructions, you can also add [Jinja](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wholroyd.jinja) too.