# Visual Studio Code and Jinja templates

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I use VS code since a while with some Extensions.
All is perfect expect when I use Flask.

Prettier put all flask code glued together, and intellisence is not working with flask code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} {% block style %} body {color: red; } {% endblock %}
{% block body %} you must provide a name {% endblock %}
```

What can I do to make it work with flask (trie flask-snippets)?

I run it in virtuel env (run before lauch vscode).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What extensions are you running?
What is your configuration for these extensions?

Comment: This is not "flask code". It is Jinja https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml

Comment: I use: Auto rename Tag / Barcket Pair Colorized 2 / C/C++ / Code Runner / Code Spell Checker / Color Highlight / Debugger for Chrome / Debugger for FIrefox / Indent-raindow / Excel Viewer / HTML CSS support / IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML / JavaScript (ES6) code snippets / Live Server / Live server Preview / Prettier / Python / Setting Sync / SVG Viewer / TODO highlight / vscode-icons

Comment: Thx to cricket_007, I've try Jinja extensions. It's better but no intellisense.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the misundestoods I've done:

1 VScode language selection is based on the file type (.html). Jinja code is inside html file, so VScode highlight html code, not jinja.

2 I've install the Better Jinja extension thx to  cricket_007. To make it work, I need to select jinja html in the bottom of VScode.  The problem is now jinja are highlight but all html highlight and autocomplete as disable. Is there a way to activate html + jinja highlight/autocomplete ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The aforementioned solutions did not quite work for me. I either lost highlighting, autocompletion or autoformatting.

I finally found a solution that gave me all of that:

1. Install "Better Jinja" or "Django" (better syntax highlighting within double quotes) plugin
2. Install "djLint" plugin
3. Press `CTRL + Shift + P` and type `open settings json` + `Enter`

This is my config and it works great for my jinja templates. djLint has more filetype-specific options to offer (see extension-description in VS Code).

```json
// settings.json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "jinja2": "html",
    "jinja-html": "html",
    "django-html": "html",
},
"[jinja]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},
"[jinja-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
},
```

My jinja-templates use the extension `.jinja2`. To make it work with the "Django" plugin I add this to my settings:

```json
// settings.json
"files.associations": {
    "*.jinja2": "django-html"
},
```

The only complaint I have now is that I can't get the linked editing of tags to work :-D

Comment: This is so _very_ close on my system. There are a couple of red squiggles on the start and end of the jinja blocks but it's by far the least frustrating solution so far

Comment: Ignore me - the new linter has taken issue with my use of single quotes that previously didn't happen with Better Jinja alone :)

Answer (score 65):

I also had a similar problem and this is what I did to fix it :

1. Install the Better Jinja plugin. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml)

- This will allow you to change the file association from plain "HTML" to "jinja-html" (it's on the lower right part of my vscode screen), and this will stop jinja codes from sticking to one another on save.
- At this stage your intellisense will not work anymore, causing a lot of annoyance, so :

2. Go to preferences >> settings >> type "file associations" in the search settings bar, click on "edit settings.json"
3. Finally add the following line to the settings.json file :

   ```
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {"jinja-html": "html"},
   ```
4. Restart your vscode. Every time you open an html file with jinja templating codes, as long as jinja-html is selected (not HTML!), prettify won't mess it up, and your intellisense should be working just fine. :)

If you use the Material Icon Theme extension, the file icon breaks after associating .html files with jinja-html.

To solve that, add this to your settings.json

```json
    "material-icon-theme.languages.associations": {
        "jinja-html": "html"
    },
    "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "jinja-html"
   },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "jinja-html": "html"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've open the settings.json file but I'm not sure where to put the line? At the total end after the last closed bracket?

Comment: You can insert it anywhere, anywhere within the outermost curly brackets. (Don't forget to add comma appropriately.)

Below is an example : 

{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--generate-members"
    ],
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--ignore",
        "E402"
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "jinja-html": "html"
    }
}

Comment: This adds syntax highliting but removes IntelliSense autocomplete

Comment: This answer worked overall, but step 2 wasn't followable for me (after searching for "file associations", there was no "edit settings.json" option – fwiw, using VSCode 1.63.2 on Mac OS 12.0.1).  Instead, I edited workspace settings from the command palette, and then added the lines from [Scott Gutthart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66307360/274786) within the braces of `"settings": {}`.

Comment: This works, but you may run into issues when you try to comment out HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312056/visual-studio-code-comment-in-html-files#comment119392084_62664301 which can be addressed by understanding this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302254/5049813

Answer (score 18):

add this like the screenshot below

```
    "files.associations": {
     "*.html": "jinja-html"
    },
```

[[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4bHa.jpg)]

Comment: This is an answer

Comment: this worked for me as well (after installing better jinja plugin).

Answer (score 13):

I have tried everything but at last, it worked for me.

1. Install the Better Jinja plugin.
2. Install the django plugin
3. Then go to settings `by pressing ctrl+,`, and search for file associations and goto settings.json and edit the following:

   `"files.associations": { "*.html": "jinja-html" },`

"emmet.includeLanguages": {"jinja-html": "html"},

Comment: This made jinja-specific intellisense work for me! There's no need to edit any json files now though (VSCode version 1.60.0), since you can edit the key-value pairs directly from the settings.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, so I tried the solutions from Ataua and Moby J, but wasn't able to get them to work. Maybe because I'm using Prettier globally.

Here's what worked for me:

There's a project called [Unibeautify](https://unibeautify.com/) that seems kind of like a "one ring to rule them all" for tying together personalized settings across different formatters and filetypes.

It has a VS Code extension, [VSCode-Unibeautify](https://github.com/Unibeautify/vscode).

After installing the extension, you need to create a config file and tell VS Code where to find it. You can create and [customize](https://assistant.unibeautify.com/#/setup) your own config if you want to use it for multiple languages, but here's what worked for me for Jinja:

```yaml
# unibeautifyrc.yaml
HTML:
  beautifiers:
    - JS-Beautify
    - Pretty Diff
```

and then, in your vscode settings:

```json
// settings.json
  "unibeautify.defaultConfig": "/PATH/TO/unibeautifyrc.yaml",
  "unibeautify.enabled": true,
  "[jinja-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Glavin001.unibeautify-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
```

What I've done also, is to associate html files with the Jinja filetype in my project's `settings.json`. This helps if you just want to limit the use of Unibeautify to just Jinja files on a project by project basis. I think you could also make the below `*.html` more specific to your templates directory if you prefer.

```json
// MYPROJECT/.vscode/settings.json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "jinja-html"
  }
}
```

This solution is powered by [JS-Beautify](https://js-beautify.com/) which seems to work well with Jinja and powers Atoms [atom-beautify](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify) extension, also by the same author of Unibeautify, [Glavin001](https://github.com/Glavin001), a beautiful individual.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from [Mobi J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12255850/moby-j) helped me but I think it was icomplete.
What did solve the same issue I was having was to add those two lines at the very ending of settings.json (**before** the last closing bracket):

```
    "emmet.includeLanguages": { "jinja-html": "html" },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.emmet"
```

I actually did so by navigating Settings (**Ctrl** + **,** on Linux), but the result is just that addition to the settings.json file.

After that change, both intellisense and emmet are working, in .html and in .jinja files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since I'm using prettier as a global formatter, I had to add this to the settings.json :

```
"[jinja-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.emmet"
    },
```

You can add this in any part of the settings, just make sure you are within the outermost brackets and maybe paste it together with other similar settings.