# Jinja intellisense and syntax highlighting in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I see on some tutorials that some manage to use intellisense and syntax highlighting for jinja templates injected in html files on Visual Studio Code, but I cannot find the way to achieve it.
I installed the Jinja and the Better Jinja extensions but I cannot manage to make them work.
To be clear, I'd like to have intellisense and syntax highlighting for code such as the one below, in an HTML file.

```
<p>
    {% if music_style %}
    The style you entered is {{ music_style }}
    Update it in the form below
    {% else %}
    Please enter your style:
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

Comment: I posted a great working solution here: [Visual Studio Code and Jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761998/9152905)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Status Bar language option]

[image: Selecting Django HTML]

In the status bar at the bottom right right side in VS code is an option to change the language,
From HTML, change it to Django HTML by clicking it and searching on the search option and then select it.

In settings.json file, you can add the following code so that mostly everytime django templates will be taken as django-html and other times html

```
"files.associations": { // so that all html files are not recognized as django-html
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "*.html": "html"
},
```

Hope it helps you,
Thank You!