# How can I fix VS Code settings not working in WSL2 when using Jinja2 templates?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've enabled syntax highlighting and linting for Jinja2 templates in VS Code using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761998/2274117). Added this to settings.json:

```
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html.j2": "jinja-html"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "jinja-html": "html"
    },
    "[jinja-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
        "editor.detectIndentation": false,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true
    },
    "djlint.useVenv": false,
```

It works perfectly when I'm working with Windows file system, but when I open *.html.j2 files in WSL2 — the Language Mode is set to "Plain Text" and I cannot even select "Jinja HTML". How can I fix this? Both Django and djLint extensions are installed and enabled for WSL, same as for Local.